# Which certification after CCNA?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm an undergraduate student studying Computer Networks. As the title says I passed my CCNA exam last summer and I am trying to decide if taking another exam before graduation (probably during the summer) would be worth it, and if so which one.

I was thinking of studying towards a Linux system administration exam, not primarily for getting certified but rather for getting the skills that will help me further down the road. A certificate showing that I possess the skills is of course an important motive but as I said it's not my primary reason for studying. (I hope that makes sense) I enjoy learning new things and I just find it easier to focus my study on a particular topic with a specific goal in mind - in this case certification.

Do you think a certification like the Red Hat RHCSA (or Comptia Linux+) will prove useful or should I focus on getting another network certification like a CCNP?  Any other certifications that you would consider useful?

Comment: Well - what do you want to do? That's the biggest question. I'd skip Linux+ personally, especially if you already have a decent handle on it. RHCSA is no joke, and not to be taken lightly.

Comment: I hardly ever pay attention to certs.  Real world experience is what I look at.  Get a job or internship

Comment: @vCole I understand that RHCSA is not the easiest to get but I guess that makes it much more valuable. Both in terms of knowledge and on a CV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off with an [LPI Certificate](http://www.lpi.org/). The first 2 levels are not as hard as RHCSA and mean a lot in the business world.

Comment: Thanks TiZon. Do you have any experience with LPI certifications? I would like to know if the skills acquired from the LPI certs are useful out there.

Comment: Sure, Level 1 is mostly basic Linux stuff. How the kernel works, Bash, config files in linux,... You can find the full list here: http://www.lpi.org/eng/certification/the_lpic_program/lpic_1 It's the stuff that some people tend to oversee, but it will make you life a lot easier later on.